# How to use extended table fields in where condition?

Tags: acumatica

I have extended INItemLotSerial table by creating a new table InfoINItemLotSerialExtNV. The Table is left joined on InventoryID & LotSerialNbr.

I am trying to use the Extended table fields in the where condition. The fields are not show up in the INItemLotSerial. Do I have to link again the table using join or Just use the InfoINItemLotSerialExtNV in where condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you extended INItemLotSerial DAC by declaring InfoINItemLotSerialExtNV like that:

```
class InfoINItemLotSerialExtNV : PXCacheExtension<INItemLotSerial>
```

The custom fields contained in InfoINItemLotSerialExtNV should be accessible whenever INItemLotSerial is accessible. Extension DAC fields are loaded by the framework when the base DAC is loaded.

Your query should look like:

```
PXSelect<INItemLotSerial, Where<InfoINItemLotSerialExtNV.customField, Equal< ... >>
```

Answer (score 0):

In BQL expressions, you have to refer to the custom field by its BQL name in the extension class. For an example please refer to [Acumatica Customization Guide](https://help.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=433c1a7f-7e1a-4b0a-8d40-ffb1659584d1). The practice shown in documentation can be applied both to the regular DAC extension and the DAC extension mapped to an extension table.